# Elastic Beanstalk stuck in an invalid state "Warning"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Elastic Beanstalk with 2 env running. Envs are exactly the same, one for prod and one for test. During a deploy using codepipeline, which I use regularly, the test env got broken, and it is now in a WARN state with this message:

> Environment health has transitioned from Pending to Warning.
> Initialization in progress (running for 3 minutes). There are no
> instances. Unable to assume role
> "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role-dev".
> Verify that the role exists and is configured correctly.

The role exists and so the instance that has been initialised.

**Also, in the Enhanced instance health panel, there are no instances despite there's a running EC2 instance created by this beanstalk environment.**

Same if I try to rebuild environment. If I retry to deploy the code it takes 20 mins before to complete and go again in the WARN state. Code is not deployed anyway (I checked on EC2 with ssh). IN Beanstalk I can see the message "Elastic Beanstalk is updating your environment." which last for around 30 mins before to disappear. The related cloud formation stack shows a CREATE_COMPLETE state.

Does anyone know what the problem is or can point me in the right direction to debug it? I am sure it is not a problem with the deployed code, as I tried to deploy the prod working branch with the same result.

Comment: Considering the error message, do you see this role `arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role-dev` in the IAM console and does it has trust policy attached?

Comment: @ArpitJain yes the role exists and has attached policies. Also in the Trust relationships panel there is "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"

Comment: Can you share permission that you are granting to this instance role? Also does EB has service role attached to it?

Comment: @ArpitJain not sure what you mean by permission, do you want to see the policies? Or the security groups?

Comment: Yeah iam policies for the instance role and service role.

Comment: I am just suspecting whether your env has both services and instance profile and has proper policies added.

Comment: the role has AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier and AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier, plus 2 user managed policies to access S3 and SES. Inbound 80 & 22. Outbound all ports 0.0.0.0